# python pandas color irregular dates by annual colorabar

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, colorbar

I have a Pandas dataframe where each column represents an irregular date within a year (for simplicity, I just included 5):

```
['2014-02-05 12:00:00',
'2014-07-03 12:00:00',
'2014-10-21 12:00:00', 
'2014-11-01 12:00:00', 
'2014-12-09 12:00:00']
```

I'm trying to create a multiple line plot consisting of the values in each column (y-axis), colored by date in the year. This would be simple if I had data columns spanning the whole year at regular intervals, but of course I don't.

I can make a colorbar that spans the dates of 1 year:

```
z = np.arange('2014-01-01',"2015-01-01",dtype='datetime64[D]')
colors = [cm.jet(x) for x in linspace(0, 1, len(z))
df.plot(colors=colors)
```

Which gives me the following figure, because I only have 67 columns in my dataframe, not 365. [Line plot with dates not spaced correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm9sR.png)

My question is: how do I link the dates in the colorbar to the dates in my columns? Ultimately, I want a figure that looks like this (I cheated in photoshop): [My goal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKv9c.png)

Comment: what is an irregular date? mock up some data and include that in your example code and example output

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Paul. Just irregularly spaced in time, see df example below.

Comment: Take a look at this questions and its responses, then edit your question accordingly. At the moment, this is too vague and we can only speculate about what your data look like, what's wrong your current plot, and how you think the plot should actually look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples